# how to change the decimal places based on conditions?

Tags: sql

based on certain condition i had to create an expression which shows either 2 or 3 decimal points. please see the code i have used

```
=Format(IIf(Fields!checkamt.Value>0,Fields!checkamt.Value * Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,""),"#,##0.F"+CStr(Fields!DecimalPlaces.Value))
```

output is 10000F2 or 10000F3 , which should be 10000.56 or 10000.561
based on the decimal places 
which is not working . can someone help ?

Comment: Your question is not understandable,please refer this link on how to improve your question and get fast answers..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: have a look at it now

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? There is no valid SQL in your question.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the question we can follow the following steps;
1. Get the decimal Place column in your table (if not present)
2. Use

```
left(cast(round(cost,decimal_number) as char(32) ),decimal_number) as R
```

Comment: i have to calculate a salary * exchange rate. for some countries it the decimal point is 3 and for the other it is 2 . for example 9561 * 3.65 = 34961.772 if you are calulating the value of Kuwait and the same for USA becomes 9561 * 3.65 = 34961.77. the first has 3 decimal point and the second has only 2. i need an equation based on the above. please see my original equation =IIf(Fields!checkamt.Value>0,Fields!checkamt.Value * Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"")

Comment: the country can be found in this column cfgCurrencySymbol

Comment: To do what you're asking @Rinu  : write some code (or store that value) to set decimal_number to the appropriate value in the correct case. This answer solves your rounding question; what have you tried to solve this larger problem that this SO question feeds into?